# Remove extra elements from html template string

Tags: javascript, html, replace, domparser

I have an html template and I want to remove the extra `<p></p>` from it via JS.
**P.S.** I cannot have more than one empty `p`.

**Example:**

```
const htmlTemplate = `
  <p>Rich editor text</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p> // <-- Remove these extra elements
  <p>1.2.3</p>
  <p>test432</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p> // <--
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>  // <--
  <p></p>  // <--
  <p>ipsum dolor amet</p>
`
```

**Result:**

```
const result = `
  <p>Rich editor text</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>1.2.3<br></p>
  <p>test432</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>ipsum dolor amet</p>
`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Why are there empty `<p></p>` in the output? You do not want more than one empty `p` consecutively?

Comment: From the result, I can see two more `<p></p>` those I are not extra?

Comment: @NicolaeMaties, you're right

Comment: @adiga, yes there can only be one `p`

Comment: @Arthur if you recognise those extra element by providing class name, then you can easily remove them using Js class selector .

Comment: @NeerajAmoli, I can't provide classnames for extra elements in my case

Comment: You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert the string to a document object and then loop through children elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex to search and remove unwanted `<p></p>`. You can use https://regex101.com/ to get the details of the regex

```js
const htmlTemplate = `
  <p>Rich editor text</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>1.2.3</p>
  <p>test432</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>lorem</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p> 
  <p>ipsum dolor amet</p>`;

const ret = htmlTemplate.replace(/<p><\/p>([.\s]*<p><\/p>)+/ig, '<p></p>');

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Great answer! I also think `{1,}` can be replaced with `+` in you regexp.